# VSCode is not responding Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, terminal

When I opened vscode, it gave me a blank screen, then a message popped up saying `Visual Studio Code is not responding` with options of `Force quit` and `Wait`. Then I tried to open it from terminal, but with the `--verbose` option and it gave me this:

```
Error: [28422:0726/094231.469719:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(374)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
```

Can anyone give me the solution please?